# Differentiating Bellman equation

Tags: bellman-equations

Assume that we have a Bellman equation that is

$$
V(k)=\max_{0\leq k'\leq f\left(k\right)}u\left(f\left(k\right)-k'\right)+\beta V\left(k'\right)
$$
The textbook says that if we differentiate with respect to $k'$ and
set equal to $0,$ we get:
$$
u'\left(f\left(k\right)-k'\right)=\beta V'\left(k'\right)
$$

My questions are:  i) What are we differentiating here? $V(k)$? Also, how can we differentiate under the max operator?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In a sense, the Bellman equation is a definition of $V(k)$, which might be more obvious if it's written
$$
V(k):=\max_{0\leq k'\leq f\left(k\right)}u\left(f\left(k\right)-k'\right)+\beta V\left(k'\right).
$$
The operator $\max_{0\leq k'\leq f\left(k\right)}$ tells us that, to get $V(k)$, we should find the *specific* $k'$ - let's call it $k'^*$ - at which the expression $u\left(f\left(k\right)-k'\right)+\beta V\left(k'\right)$ is greatest (if such a maximum exists).

To do that, and provided the functions involved have the right properties, the first step is to take the derivative of $u\left(f\left(k\right)-k'\right)+\beta V\left(k'\right)$ with respect to $k'$ and setting the result equal to zero. So,
$$
\frac{d}{dk'}u\left(f\left(k\right)-k'\right)+\beta V\left(k'\right) = 0, 
$$
from which follows (after some math) that
$$
u'\left(f\left(k\right)-k'\right)=\beta V'\left(k'\right)
$$
*at the maximum* (given the right properties), so not everywhere, but where $k'=k'^*$.
Without further knowledge of $u$ and $V$, this gives at least an implicit rule for how to obtain $k'^*$, namely via
$$
u'\left(f\left(k\right)-k'^*\right)=\beta V'\left(k'^*\right)
$$
Because with $k'^*$ we have now found the specific $k'$ at which $u'\left(f\left(k\right)-k'\right)=\beta V'\left(k'\right)$ is greatest, we can substitute that specific value, $k'^*$, into the initial definition to get
$$
V(k):=u\left(f\left(k\right)-k'^*\right)+\beta V\left(k'^*\right).
$$
where the $\max$ operator has disappeared, as $k'^*$ evaluates the function already at the max. And we see that $V(k)$ does not depend on $k'$.

Comment: Would it be correct to write V(k) as actually V(k,k') and then differentiate both sides? I will accept this answer, if you could please write down explicitly what we are differentiating? In other  words, when we take the derivative, does the max operator disappear?

Comment: @KwameBrown $V$ only depends on $k$, not on $k'$. For a given $k$, we only care about the specific value of $k'$ where the inner function is maximized. The rest is calculus, to find a (local) maxima of a (differentiable) function, compute its derivative and set it to zero (and check a few more things).

Comment: Answer edited for clarification.

Comment: +1, nice answer

Comment: Thank you so much, this is very helpful indeed.